# Django rest create user if login not exists

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My problem: I send post request from frontend, which consists of login and password. At backend (Django) I need to check if user with that login exists. And then send response back to frontend. I found different solutions, using different django rest decorators, but when i send post request, I get 500 error.

serializers.py:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):        
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

And my js file, where I send post request:

```
const register = () => {
        Axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/users/', {
            login: loginReg,
            password: passwordReg,
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        })
    }
```

EDIT: The code below in serializers.py gives that error:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    records = RecordSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)     
    def create(self, validated_data):
        if User.objects.filter(**validated_data).exists():
            raise Exception('User already exists')
            return User.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: 500 errors implies theres a server failure- could you post the error? \

Comment: POST http://localhost:8000/api/users/ 500 (Internal Server Error)


Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)

Comment: That looks like the frontend error- can you provide the error thrown in the django webserver output?

Comment: It is not frontend error, because without checking the existing of user with same login everything works fine. Server output: AssertionError: `create()` did not return an object instance.

Comment: @10k20, you have indented return of create() method. if user don't exists, it will return None

Comment: @10k20 I agree it' not a front-end error. However you provided front-end errors instead of back end error emitting from the server.

Answer (score 1):

As per the condition you have said : You are creating a user object if the one provided does not exist (correct me if I'm wrong)

In that case the create method should be logically outside if condition where you are checking whether the user obj exists:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    records = RecordSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)     
    def create(self, validated_data):
        if User.objects.filter(**validated_data).exists():
            raise Exception('User already exists')
        return User.objects.create(**validated_data)
```